# Speed Up Search In Mongo

Tags: mongodb

```
    $documents_need_indexing = $datasources->find(array('is_indexed' => array('$exists' => false)))
```

I have 2 million documents in mongo...

This query runs really slow. Would I be better off checking for is_indexed: false and add the attribute is_indexed to all documents? (instead of after being indexed)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an index on `is_indexed` since youre doing queries based on that single field.  Without the index, its a full table scan every time.

If that field isnt on every document, then a sparse index would be even better.